# I'm having a problem triggering this classlist toggle in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am trying to trigger this CSS open in React the tutorial was in HTML but I cannot use addeventlistner or use document.queryselector so I added an onClick event to the hamburger which should handle both of those issues now I just need to toggle this Class.Please do not mark this as already answered because the answered questions are jquery and regular html related.

**Component:**

```
const Navbar = props => {
  const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
  const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('nav-links li');

  // hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //   navLinks.classList.toggle("open")
  // });
  useEffect(() => {


  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div onCLick={//I want to toggle the open class on click} className="hamburger">
          <div className="line"></div>
          <div className="line"></div>
          <div className="line"></div>
        </div>
        <ul className="nav-links">
          <li className="nav-links">About</li>
          <li className="nav-links">About</li>
          <li className="nav-links">About</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

**CSS:**

```
nav{
    height: 10vh;
    background: blue !important;
}
.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
}

/* change to classes */
.nav-links li a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px
}

.landing{
    height: 90vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.landing h1{
    margin: 100px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .nav-links{
        position: fixed;
        background: red;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        display: none;
        clip-path: circle(100px at 90% 10%);
        -webkit-clip-path: circle(100px at 90% 10%);
        z-index: 99999;
        transition: all 1s ease-out
    }

    .nav-links.open{
        clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% 10%);
        -webkit-clip-path: circle(1000px at 90% 10%);
    }

    .line{
        width: 30px;
        height: 3px;
        background: white;
        margin: 5px
    }

    nav{
        position: relative
    }

    .hamburger{
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
        right: 5%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-5%,-50%)
    }
}
```

Comment: Code shown will clearly throw error but no  errors are mentioned. Those errors are big clues

Comment: I know there are errors sir. Can you please tell me how to toggle this classlist from my onclick function? thanks

Comment: Well... ask yourself what classlist is being toggled. Quite honestly you should not be using dom methods for this at all. You almost never use dom methods in react. Not to mention you can't query for elements that haven't been rendered yet

Comment: Well what should i use to show this animation im here because i dont know how to implement this in react

Comment: You would modify state and state would determine className in render

Comment: So on Click add Class Name of State to Hamburger?

Comment: className=" {isOpen}"?

Comment: And have isopen set to null initially?

Comment: Does toggle just add the class to Line?

Comment: you will need a useState hook

Comment: Yes But does that i described work?

Comment: Yes getting closer

Comment: Ok ty so i will add a toggle to check if it is set or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should employ `state` which is React's way of helping you keep track of the current status of your component (Like when your hamburger is clicked). One of the core concepts behind React is that you define event-listeners for your JSX. So when a user interacts with your application, an event is triggered and thus the `state` of your component changes.

We use `state` to help construct your desired functionality. In this case, clicking on the hamburger would toggle the `open state` and thus we use that `state` Boolean value to help us toggle the classes of your nav-links list.

There is no need to forcefully interact with the `DOM` as you would with typical document selectors in vanilla JavaScript.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-wildflower-94e6q

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Navbar = props => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <div onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} className="hamburger">
          <div className="line" />
          <div className="line" />
          <div className="line" />
        </div>

        <ul className={open ? "nav-links" : "hide"}>
          <li className="nav-links">About</li>
          <li className="nav-links">About</li>
          <li className="nav-links">About</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Navbar />, rootElement);
```